# How to call excel macro contained in individual module (not in sheet)

Tags: vba, tcl

Using the following code to run a macro from within a workbook:

```
set app [::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application]
[$app Workbooks] Open c:/MyMacroBook.xlsx
$app Run Macro1
```

But how to call when there are multiple macros with same name in different modules?

e.g. `Module1` has `Macro1`, and `Module2` has `Macro1`

Tried the following but didn't work:

```
set app [::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application]
[$app Workbooks] Open c:/MyMacroBook.xlsx
$app Run Module1!Macro1
$app Run Module2!Macro1
```

Comment: try `$app Run Module1.Macro1` (note the full stop in place of an exclamation mark)

Comment: Tried but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't work like that - you have to have the Excel workbook open and then call individual macro name.

```
set app [::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application]
[$app Workbooks] Open c:/MyMacroBook.xlsx
$app Run Macro1
```

Not sure what happens to a duplicate macro name